# How to add new language source directories in gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to have the following working gradle script for arbitrary language `foo`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/gen-java"
        }
        foo {
            srcDir "${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/gen-foo"
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir "${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/gen-test-java"
        }
        foo {
            srcDir "${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/gen-test-foo"
        }
    }
}
```

I also want to have standard `foo` source directories at `src/main/foo`,  `src/test/foo`.

How do I write a gradle plugin to achieve such functionality? Is there possibility to do that?

I have a "solution-like" workaround for my needs posted below but still want to understand the right way to add new language source directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve such a functionality one should extend existing source sets (or at least `main` and `test` source sets). It looks like `main` and `test` source sets [are defined in `JavaPlugin`](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/trigger-for-when-new-language-source-sets-are-added/13373). Extending is possible through `Convention` object.

```
public class FooPlugin implements Plugin<ProjectInternal> {
    @Override
    public void apply(ProjectInternal project) {
        project.getPluginManager().apply(JavaPlugin.class);
        FooExtension ext = project.getExtensions().create(
            "foo",
            FooExtension.class,
            project,
            project.getFileResolver()
        );
        SourceSetContainer cont = (SourceSetContainer) project.getProperties().get("sourceSets");
        cont.all((SourceSet ss) -> {
            String name = ss.getName();
            File sources = project.file("src/" + name + "/foo");
            FooSourceSet fss = ext.getSourceSetsContainer().maybeCreate(name);
            SourceDirectorySet sds = fss.getFoo();
            sds.srcDir(sources);
            Convention sourceSetConvention = (Convention) InvokerHelper.getProperty(ss, "convention");
            sourceSetConvention.getPlugins().put("foo", fss);
        });
        project.task("compileFoo");
    }
}

public class FooExtension {

    private final NamedDomainObjectContainer<FooSourceSet> sourceSetsContainer;

    public FooExtension(Project project, FileResolver fileResolver) {
        sourceSetsContainer = project.container(
            FooSourceSet.class,
            new FooSourceSetFactory(fileResolver)
        );
    }

    public NamedDomainObjectContainer<FooSourceSet> getSourceSetsContainer() {
        return sourceSetsContainer;
    }

    public void srcDir(String file) {
        sourceSetsContainer.getByName("main").getFoo().srcDir(file);
    }
}

public class FooSourceSetFactory implements NamedDomainObjectFactory<FooSourceSet> {

    private final FileResolver fileResolver;

    public FooSourceSetFactory(FileResolver fileResolver) {
        this.fileResolver = fileResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public FooSourceSet create(String name) {
        return new DefaultFooSourceSet(name, fileResolver);
    }
}

public interface FooSourceSet {
    public String getName();
    public SourceDirectorySet getFoo();
    public FooSourceSet foo(Closure clsr);
}

public class DefaultFooSourceSet implements FooSourceSet {

    final String name;
    final SourceDirectorySet foo;

    public DefaultFooSourceSet(String displayName, FileResolver fileResolver) {
        this.name = displayName;
        DefaultDirectoryFileTreeFactory ddftf = new DefaultDirectoryFileTreeFactory();
        foo = new DefaultSourceDirectorySet(name, fileResolver, ddftf);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public SourceDirectorySet getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    @Override
    public FooSourceSet foo(Closure clsr) {
        ConfigureUtil.configure(clsr, foo);
        return this;
    }
}

public class CompileFooTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void compileFoo() {
        SourceSetContainer cont = (SourceSetContainer) getProject().getProperties().get("sourceSets");
        cont.all((SourceSet ss) -> {
            FooSourceSet fss = getProject()
                .getExtensions()
                .getByType(FooExtension.class)
                .getSourceSetsContainer()
                .maybeCreate(ss.getName());
            System.out.println("directories under " + ss.getName()
                + ": " + fss.getFoo().getSrcDirs());
        });
    }
}
```

Task `compileFoo` demonstrates that plugin actually works. Given the build script snippet from the question it prints the lines like these:

```
directories under main: [<root>/src/main/foo, <root>/build/generated-sources/gen-foo]
directories under test: [<root>/src/test/foo, <root>/build/generated-sources/gen-test-foo]
```

Answer (score 5):

The source code for your use case would be pretty long, but here's a couple of pointers that will hopefully get you going.

Take a look at the [Scala Plugin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/scala/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/scala). It does exactly what you need (as it looks like you are following the java conventions for sources), and also much more. If you are trying to write any plugin, I recommend checking out the whole gradle source code.

The exact places you want to see are:

1. [`ScalaBasePlugin#configureSourceSetDefaults`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/scala/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/scala/ScalaBasePlugin.java) - this is where the top level configuration happens
2. [`DefaultScalaSourceSet`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/scala/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/DefaultScalaSourceSet.java) - the actual source set class

In your case, your probably just want to rename all `scala` strings to `foo` and remove all the configuration you don't need (such as the actual compilation).

The plugin illustrates how to add the default source directories and the method:

```
public ScalaSourceSet scala(Closure configureClosure) {
    configure(configureClosure, getScala());
    return this;
}
```

takes care of the addition of generated sources. Basically it just takes the default source directory factory and uses that. You can use injection to add all the default gradle factories (see the Scala plugin, simply using the `javax.inject.Inject` works).

You can also check the groovy plugin. Notice that e.g. the [`DefaultGroovySourceSet`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/e1f48885295c7373ea402b0e0237cde3a74c23a0/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/DefaultGroovySourceSet.java) looks like the one in the scala plugin.